# Min Max Image Histogram Stretching

Tags: python, image-processing

I have a problem with fitting the histogram of an image to a specific range to get a better contrast.

First of all the data that I use starting from input image+histogram over to my output image+histogram to the output that I want+histogram:

[image: My input image]

[image: Histogram of input image]

[image: My output image]

[image: The histogram from my output image]

[image: I want it to look like this (looks a lot smoother)]

[image: Histogram of the output image that I want]

The description of the method in the program that I used just says "Maps black to the minimal intensity and white to the maximal intensity".

Here is the code to do the mapping:

```
for y in range(0, h):
    for x in range(0, w):
        image[y,x] = (((image[y,x] - smallest) / diff)  * 65535)
```

In this code is smallest the minimal intensity in the original image and diff the difference between max and min intensity.

**What do I need to do, to get a smoother histogram in the end?**

Thanks for helping!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `image` is of an integer type, then `(image[y,x] - smallest) / diff)` is a smaller integer -- this operation rounds down the result, effectively quantifying the input gray levels.

To prevent this from happening, pre-compute the multiplier as this:

```
scale = 65535 / diff
image[y,x] = (image[y,x] - smallest) * scale
```

Alternatively, cast the pixel value to a floating-point number before computing the mapping, then cast back to integer to store it back in the `image` array.

Comment: @PhilippMarquardt: that is hard to believe. Could you share exactly what you tried? Did you reload the image?

Comment: Sorry i looked at it again and found the error. Your fix does the right thing. I read the image with `image = cv2.imread(im, 0)` which converted the image to 8 bit and did some weird stuff. I changed it to `image = cv2.imread(im, -1)` and it works fine now. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You may want to try `scikit-image exposure` module's histogram equalization (it generally yields better results than contrast / histogram stretching):

```
from skimage.io import imread
from skimage.exposure import equalize_hist
import matplotlib.pylab as plt
image = imread('../lc.png')
image = image / np.max(image)
plt.figure(figsize=(15,10))
plt.subplot(221)
plt.imshow(image, cmap='gray')
plt.title('original image')
plt.subplot(222)
plt.hist(image.ravel(), normed=True)
plt.title('histogram')
image = equalize_hist(image)
plt.subplot(223)
plt.imshow(image, cmap='gray')
plt.title('contrast-enhanced image')
plt.subplot(224)
plt.hist(image.ravel(), normed=True)
plt.title('histogram')
plt.show()
```

[image]